# Speed up AD Group/Membership Report in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I'm pretty new to Powershell scripting and I was looking for ways to go through an entire forest and select only groups with specific string included in their AD group name and then to pull the full member list for each group and then include their AD account status/object class as well. This is what I'm using currently... any help would be appreciated as this currently runs slower  than.. well it runs really slow.

```
$OutputFileName = "Test File.csv"
$Data=@()

if (Test-Path $OutputFileName) {
  Remove-Item $OutputFileName
}
$Tab = [char]9
foreach($Domain in Get-ADForest | select -ExpandProperty domains){
    Foreach($ADGroup in get-adgroup -Filter {name -like "Test*"} -server $Domain){
        Foreach($Member in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -server $Domain){
        
        $Data = Get-ADUser -Identity $Member -Properties enabled | 
            Select-Object @{Label = "AD Group";Expression = {$ADGroup.name}},  
            @{Name = "NTID";Expression = {$Member.samaccountname}},
            @{Name = "Object Class";Expression = {$Member.objectclass}},
            @{Name = "Account Status";Expression = {if (($_.Enabled -eq 'TRUE')  ) {'Enabled'} Else {'Disabled'}}}
            

$Data | Export-Csv -Path c:\users\xxxxx\Test File.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Export-Csv` is slowing you down, Disk I/O on each iteration of the loop is killing your script. I see you're defining `$data` as a `System.Array` however I don't see you adding elements to it on the iterations. `System.Array` is slow compared to `Collections.Generic.List` or `Collections.ArrayList`. On the inner loop of `Get-ADGroupMember` I see you are always using `Get-ADUser`, however, if one of those groups contains a sub-group as Member your script will throw (you should add error handling for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-ADGroupMember` is an awfully inefficient cmdlet for a few reasons, so instead of this:

```
Foreach($ADGroup in Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "Test*"} -server $Domain){
  Foreach($Member in Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -server $Domain){
    $Data = Get-ADUser -Identity $Member -Properties enabled |
    ...
```

Let's cut out `Get-ADGroupMember` to save many, many AD lookups:

```
# Save results to a single list object
$Result = @()

Foreach($Domain in Get-ADForest | select -ExpandProperty domains){
  Foreach ($ADGroup in (Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "Test*"' -Server $Domain)) { 
    # Cut out Get-ADGroupMember --
    Foreach ($Member in (Get-ADObject -Filter "MemberOf -EQ '$($ADGroup.DistinguishedName)'" -Properties userAccountControl,samaccountname -Server $Domain)) {
      $Data = '' |
        Select-Object @{Label = "AD Group";Expression = {$ADGroup.name}},  
          @{Name = "NTID";Expression = {$Member.samaccountname}},
          @{Name = "Object Class";Expression = {$Member.objectclass}},
          @{Name = "Account Status";Expression = {
            if (($Member.userAccountControl -band 2) -eq 2 ) {'Disabled'} 
            Else {'Enabled'}
          }}
      $Result += $Data
    }
  }
}

# Do a single export.
$Result | Export-Csv -Path c:\users\xxxxx\Test File.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

This example takes about 1/100th of the time on my machine to return 900 users

Comment: This is great, by using `Get-ADUser` with a `-Filter "MemberOf....` he is nullifying the possibility of a throw as I mentioned on my comment. This could be improved even further by using a `Generic.List` or `ArrayList`. Also `Enabled` is a default property returned by `Get-ADuser` hence no need to call for it.

Comment: Man this works so much faster! I have only one issue though, it's only pulling Users and I need it to pull all objects. Is that because of the filter that is being applied? Would it be possible to avoid it throwing an error to use Get-ADObject instead?

Comment: @tossaire You can use `Get-ADObject` in place of `Get-ADUser` without any issues, but you need to add `samaccountname` property like `-properties enabled,samaccountname` since it's not included by default.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thank you so much! I made the edit to include the samaccount name and boom. It grabs everything that I need now and runs in about 15 minutes instead of 10 hours :)

Comment: Well, I just need to figure out why it's labelling everything with disabled and we'll be good. It's always something hahahah

Comment: @tossaire Whoops! I didn't look closely - `Enabled` is actually a function of `userAccountControl`, so we need to check that instead. I've updated my answer

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I added in `-Server $Domain` into the line `Foreach ($ADGroup in (Get-ADGroup -Filter 'name -like "Test*"'` as it looks like it's only hitting one out of three domains. Not sure if that will fix it but fingers crossed.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale epic fail on my end. For some reason it's not pulling all of the objects in the domains. If I have domain1, domain2, domain3 it's seeing the AD groups in all of them, but only reporting the objects that are in say domain1? and I still can't get the damn loop to work right.

Comment: @tossaire yeah I don't have multiple domains, so I left it out where it mattered by accident :X (updated). You also need to add it to `Get-ADObject` if you haven't already

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Whelp, it takes hours to run but it's also returning over 80k lines over multiple domains but holy shit I think it's all good. Thank you so much for the help! Yeah I put the `Get-ADObject` in earlier.